# If (this = that) - what actually happens here?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

It's hard to ask search this question and the answer would help clean up my code a bit.  Basically, in PHP, if I use:

```
if (this = that)
```

what is going on?  Is it checking that the variable got assigned correctly or is it checking the truth of "that" and as an aside also assigning it to "this?"

I ask because it would be easier if the answer were the former due to it taking an extra line to assign it, then run the conditional, and then use the return of it later.  I know it's miniscule to be harping over one line, but over an entire script it can add up.  Thanks for any help.

TO CLARIFY: I want to essentially write the equivalent of the following:

```
$this = something;
if ($this)
  do things with $this
```

by writing it as

```
if ($this = $myFunctionCall)
  do things with $this;
```

all assuming that $this isn't set beforehand.

Comment: You could test it :) You'd remember, this way.

Comment: also it should be: if (this == that)

Comment: Yeah, I really need to setup a XAMMP or something because it's such a pain to test these things when you have to upload to your server and such.

Comment: @Jamie, he's specifically asking about assignment in an if statement, so i think he meant what he has.

Comment: @ Jamie: no, that's part of the question, I want to assign that to this, not check it against it.  I'm asking if I assign it in the conditional, does the if check the truth of the assignment or the truth of "that"

Comment: @jamie: I'm pretty sure he knows what happens if he evaluates this == that. He is wondering what happens when the above code is executed.

Comment: `yum install php httpd` *runs*

Comment: @ignacio, i bet if he's installing xampp its because he's running windows.

Comment: Of course, what *actually* happens is that your co-workers get annoyed at you for writing code that's hard to read :)

Comment: @nathan: That's why I'm running ;)

Comment: Don't do this, the intent is obscured.  Do the assignment on one line, the evaluation on another.

Comment: @linus72982 There's also [codepad](http://codepad.org/) for simple problems :)

Comment: I wouldn't think that would be hard to read, then again I'm not working with anyone nor am I intending my script to be extended or worked on or used by anyone else so I probably won't need to worry about it for my current uses.

Comment: @ignacio, doh,  i totally glazed over everything outside of the codeblock...

Comment: @xanadont I agree, while you can see what's going, 99.9% of the time that you see `if(this = that)` it's a typo rather than intentional. IDEs actually highlight it as a probable error. So if another developer picks up your code, that will jump out as a mistake. At the very least you should leave a comment saying it's not a mistake, and by the time you've done that, you may as well do the 'standard' way of assigning in the line above the `if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's assigning, and then it's checking the "trueness" of the value that was assigned.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I wanted to hear, thanks to all the answers below as well.

Answer (score 2):

its checking the "truthiness" of `this` iirc, the assignment occurs before evaluation

Comment: @prodigitalson, one of my favorite non-words

Answer (score 2):

Linus,

Regardless of if it works, I'm not a fan of the assignment-within-test approach. I think it's too-easy to overlook the ASSIGNMENT, which is a potential (and easily avoidable) source of future bugs... I think this commonly used coding paradigm is "a bit sloppy".

In almost all "modern" languages you can create and assign a local variable in one step... which I find succinct, self explanatory, and emminently readable.

```
var stuff = getStuff();
if (stuff == null) {
  Message("Sorry, no stuff found.");
  return;
}
```

verses

```
var thing, widget, stuff, foo;

.... then many lines later ...
if ((stuff=getStuff())) {
  // do things with stuff
} else {
  // no stuff
  Message("Sorry, no stuff found.");
}
```

As you can tell, I'm also anything but a fan of the old "structured programming" adage that there should be one exit-point per function/method/script. Instead, I believe that whenever we strike a situtation that means we can't continue here, we should leave, by the most direct route possible. This is JUST a personal preference. You can make valid arguements for any approach.

One word of advise: Whatever you do, do it **CONSISTENTLY!** The programmer who (a few years down the track, when you've moved on) is charged with enhancing your code will catch-on quick enough to "your style". They may not like it, but that's really not important, so long as they UNDERSTAND it. There's always a trade-off between succinctness and explicitness... there is no "correct" style... just some styles seem to WORK better than others, in the long run.

KISS it my son, and booger to brevity.

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score 1):

It will first set $this to $that, and then if $this == true, the contents of the if statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You would be assigning the value of `that` to `this` and checking if `this` then evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it first assigns and then checks if it's true.

Like when traversing MySQL tables:

```
while ($row = mysql_get_row($query)) {
  ...
}
```

When it doesn't work anymore (a `false` pops up), the loop breaks. It assigns and checks validity, all in one line.

Answer (score 1):

I want to say that it assigns as well as check the value, purely based on this code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    // Query actions
}
```

Which we all know loops until there are no more results to process. `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false` when no results remain, but the value is still assigned, hence, it doesn't check that the value was assigned, but the *value* that was assigned.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment operation (`$foo = 'bar'`) is an *expression* in which a value is assigned to a variable. The *expression* as a whole returns a value. The returned value is the value that was assigned.

So, `if ($foo = 'bar')` is synonymous to:

```
$foo = 'bar';
if ('bar') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Some demo code

```
$false = false;
$true = true;
$someVar = true;

function someFunk() {
  return false;
}

if ($someVar = $false) {
  echo "True \n";
} else {
  echo "False \n";
}

if ($someVar = $true) {
  echo "True \n";
} else {
  echo "False \n";
}


if ($someVar = someFunk()) {
  echo "True \n";
} else {
  echo "False \n";
}
```

This outputs

```
False 
True 
False
```

http://codepad.org/8JxX8MYP

Answer (score 0):

if (this = that)

`step 1->`
this=that; //copy data from that to this

`step 2->`
If copy succeed then the code became like this

if (1) //true

If copy failed then the code became like this

if (0) //false

Comment: How would an assignment fail?

Comment: $str='hi';  $str=print_r($array);